# WinForms.net: a control for one project only

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, toolbox

I want to make a composite control which I could drag to form multiple times, but this control should reside in one project only. I do not like the idea of making a control, and installing it to be visible to all projects in a Visual Studio 2010 Toolbox.

So, I assumed that the UserControl is what I needed. I created one, but now can't drag it to a form or find it in the Toolbox.

Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > AutoToolboxPopulate is set to True.

Answer (score 2):

I had to compile the project to make UserControl appear in the Toolbox.